# WSO2 Authorization for web application

Tags: authorization, xacml, abac, xacml3, wso2-identity-server

I have cloned https://github.com/pac4j/play-pac4j-scala-demo app and configured with wso2 identity server on saml2. After validation of saml2 request , i have redirected to HTML page where I created two button. Create Lecture & View Lecture.On click of Create button , play Lecture controller with create Action is called

Now I wanted to achieve access control like teacher(role) can create lecture but student can only view it.

So i created Policy XACML and it was working with try it option of WSO2 .
But when I integrate with my application, both my users(teacher & student role) were not able to login when i have checked Enable Authorization in Local outbound.
And if i unchecked Enable Authorization in Local outbound both my users login and able to access resource http://localhost:9000/createLecture.

I have few questions.

1. What could be p**ossible reason policy not working when integrated with application**. Please note I have validated its Published & Enabled.
2. **Why is it authorizing at time of authentication.**

Also I want to ***read response of Authorization to enable disable create button. So do I need Entitlement Mediator or what could be other possible solution?***

### XACML Policy

```xml
<Policy xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17"  PolicyId="policyteacherstudent" RuleCombiningAlgId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:rule-combining-algorithm:first-applicable" Version="1.0">
    <Description>sample policy</Description>
    <Target>
    </Target>
    <Rule Effect="Permit" RuleId="test">
        <Target>
            <AnyOf>
                <AllOf>
                    <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-regexp-match">
                        <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">http://localhost:9000/createLecture/</AttributeValue>
                        <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true">
                        </AttributeDesignator>
                    </Match>
                    <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
                        <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">read</AttributeValue>
                        <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true">
                        </AttributeDesignator>
                    </Match>
                </AllOf>
            </AnyOf>
        </Target>
        <Condition>
            <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:or">
                <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-is-in">
                    <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">teacher</AttributeValue>
                    <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="http://wso2.org/claims/role" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true">
                    </AttributeDesignator>
                </Apply>
            </Apply>
        </Condition>
    </Rule>
    <Rule Effect="Deny" RuleId="testdeny">
        <Target>
            <AnyOf>
                <AllOf>
                    <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-regexp-match">
                        <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">http://localhost:9000/createLecture/</AttributeValue>
                        <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true">
                        </AttributeDesignator>
                    </Match>
                    <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
                        <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">read</AttributeValue>
                        <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true">
                        </AttributeDesignator>
                    </Match>
                </AllOf>
            </AnyOf>
        </Target>
        <Condition>
            <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:or">
                <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-is-in">
                    <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">student</AttributeValue>
                    <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="http://wso2.org/claims/role" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true">
                    </AttributeDesignator>
                </Apply>
            </Apply>
        </Condition>
    </Rule>
</Policy>
```

Thanks
Priyanka

Answer (score 0):

The reason for not hitting this policy is this does not have a target.

When a policy is evaluated it evaluates the target first and if the current requirements match the target then it evaluates the rules

Example

```
<Policy xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17" PolicyId="authn_role_based_policy_template"        RuleCombiningAlgId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:rule-combining-algorithm:first-applicable" Version="1.0">
   <Description>This policy template provides ability to authorize users to a given service provider(defined by SP_NAME) in the authentication flow based on the roles of the user (defined by ROLE_1 and ROLE_2). Users who have at least one of the given roles, will be allowed and any others will be denied.</Description>
   <Target>
      <AnyOf>
         <AllOf>
            <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
               <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">SP_NAME</AttributeValue>
               <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="http://wso2.org/identity/sp/sp-name" Category="http://wso2.org/identity/sp" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="false"/>
            </Match>
            <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
               <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">authenticate</AttributeValue>
               <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="http://wso2.org/identity/identity-action/action-name" Category="http://wso2.org/identity/identity-action" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="false"></AttributeDesignator>
            </Match>
         </AllOf>
      </AnyOf>
   </Target>
   <Rule Effect="Permit" RuleId="permit_by_roles">
      <Condition>
         <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:or">
            <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-is-in">
               <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">ROLE_1</AttributeValue>
               <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="http://wso2.org/claims/role" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"/>
            </Apply>
            <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-is-in">
               <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">ROLE_2</AttributeValue>
               <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="http://wso2.org/claims/role" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"/>
            </Apply>
         </Apply>
      </Condition>
   </Rule>
   <Rule Effect="Deny" RuleId="deny_others"/>
</Policy>
```